# What is the purpose of using getServerSideProps() instead of a regular asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I recently tried using `getServerSideProps()`. There must be a reason why it was made, but its utility appears to me like that of a normal `async` function.

For instance, I am fetching user data with Prisma and NextAuth. I could put the logic I wrote in `getServerSideProps()` into just a regular `async` function inside my functional component and the effect would be the same.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed having an asynchronous function in your component and calling it inside an `useEffect` does the same thing in terms of getting  data from an API. The difference is about where the request is made.

The normal one makes it in the browser while `getServerSideProps` runs on the server. Here is what the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run) says:

> `getServerSideProps` only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser. If a page uses `getServerSideProps`, then:
>
> - When you request this page directly, `getServerSideProps` runs at request time, and this page will be pre-rendered with the returned props
> - When you request this page on client-side page transitions through `next/link` or `next/router`, Next.js sends an API request to the server, which runs `getServerSideProps`
>
> `getServerSideProps` returns JSON which will be used to render the page. All this work will be handled automatically by Next.js, so you don’t need to do anything extra as long as you have `getServerSideProps` defined.

`getServerSideProps` is preferable for example when making a call to an API with a secret key that you don't want people steal by inspecting the page with the browser development tools.

And there are some cases where you can only use `getServerSideProps`. For example if you are using a database package that cannot run in the browser, `Prisma` for example:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
  return { props: { posts } };
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! That clarifies it!